# How to register a Facebook Application via API/PHP?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to provide a system that automatically registers/creates Facebook Applications for its users. Unfortunately I did not find a way to register a new Application via API.

I know that this is possible, because I saw this e.g. here:
http://apps.facebook.com/applicationbuilderl/Setup/New.aspx

How can I register a new Facebook Application (I need to get back AppId, Secret and Key), with a form to fill out, on my website or within my facebook app?

Thanks a lot,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using the old Javascript SDK:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/FB.Connect.createApplication

As the name of the SDK lets assume this is all deprecated stuff and will not be longer supported and/or removed by facebook.